# Custom Init Method not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I'm trying to populate UITextFields inside a UITableViewController with a click of a cell. So, I created an init method like:

```
- (id)initWithObjetoFormulario:(ObjetoFormularioGerenciador *)umObjeto
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.objetoFormulario = umObjeto;
            }
    return self;
}
```

In my `ViewDidLoad` I put the line `if(self.objetoFormulario){` and after that link the UITextFields to my Object. I don't think there's anything wrong at this point.

So, my Second TableViewController is a SearchDisplayController, it finds the Data I need and at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I have:

```
ObjetoFormularioGerenciador *objeto = [[ObjetoFormularioGerenciador alloc] init];
    [objeto RecebeArrayComDadosECriaObjetoFormularioGerenciador:_arrayComDados eEmail:  [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   GerenciarSeriesTableViewController *gerenciador = [[GerenciarSeriesTableViewController  alloc] initWithObjetoFormulario:objeto];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gerenciador animated:NO];
```

As I don't have the actual objects in my cells, I call a method to retrieve the object according to the cell entry, that is working as well, now, it opens a blank TableView when I click the cell. It should go Back to my tableView with static Cells containing UITextFields and populate them.

When I use this code:

```
ObjetoFormularioGerenciador *objeto = [[ObjetoFormularioGerenciador alloc] init];
[objeto RecebeArrayComDadosECriaObjetoFormularioGerenciador:_arrayComDados eEmail:[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
GerenciarSeriesTableViewController *gerenciador = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GerenciarSeriesTableViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gerenciador animated:NO];
```

It does open the TableView I want, but it doesn't populate the UITextFields as I didn't pass any object.

Thanks.

Comment: `RecebeArrayComDadosECriaObjetoFormularioGerenciador:eEmail` the worst method name ever.

Comment: thanks:) It is just easier to keep track of what I'm doing when it's like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you really don't generally have custom `init` methods for view controllers, but rather rely upon the standard ones, and then once the view controller has been instantiated, you'd just set the property then, e.g.:

```
ObjetoFormularioGerenciador *objeto = ... // create and configure objeto

GerenciarSeriesTableViewController *gerenciador = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GerenciarSeriesTableViewController"];
gerenciador.objetoFormulario = objeto;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gerenciador animated:NO];
```

You can also have a segue between the two view controllers, give it an identifier, and then call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:...]`, and then set the `objetoFormulario` in the `prepareForSegue` method. But the above technique should work fine, too.

Comment: Perfect, that works very well. About the custom init methods though, isn't that used often? Just curious. Thanks.

Comment: @Jorge In a NIB-based project you can use custom `init` methods (that call the standard `initWithNibName:bundle:`). But in a storyboard world, you're often letting the storyboard or the segue instantiate the view controller and subviews, so it doesn't make sense to use custom `init` method. But iOS 5 introduced `prepareForSegue`, to let you use standard `initWithCoder`, but provide mechanism for passing of data to the destination controller. Thus, with storyboards, you don't generally use custom `init` methods with view controllers (or any UIKit subclasses either).